# QField - display of entries for 1:n relationships

Tags: qfield

I'm working on a QField project where I've defined 1:n relationships between points/polygons and tables. The relationship itself works fine, and the information is recorded in the tables as planned however the entries in the QField interface look unspecific - there are only rows with zeroes like shown the picture below.

How do I need to adjust the settings that the name of a specific field is shown in this field?

[image]

---

I tried different settings in the display properties without any changes in the appearance of this field.

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure Display name in Display properties in Layer properties (https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/vector_properties.html#display-properties).